# Parsing a URL query string into a map of parameters with XPath

Tags: xpath, xslt-3.0, xpath-3.0, xpath-3.1

What would be the most readable way to parse a URL query string into a `{ 'param': 'value' }` map in XSLT/XPath 3.0?

Note: this is the inverse function of the one described in [Building a URL query string from a map of parameters with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336560/building-a-url-query-string-from-a-map-of-parameters-with-xpath).

Update: I neglected to mention that the function should support multi-value parameters such as `a=1&a=2`, and ideally parse them as an `xs:string*` sequence.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
let $querystring := "a=1&amp;b=2&amp;c=3"
return 
  ( tokenize($querystring, "&amp;") 
    ! (let $param := tokenize(., "=") 
      return map:entry($param[1], $param[2]) ) 
  ) => map:merge()
```

In order to support multiple values, you could can apply the [$options parameter](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-map-merge) specifying what to do with `duplicates`:

```
declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
let $querystring := "a=1&amp;b=2&amp;a=3"
return 
  ( tokenize($querystring, "&amp;") 
    ! (let $param := tokenize(., "=") 
      return map:entry($param[1], $param[2]) ) 
  ) => map:merge(map:entry('duplicates', 'combine'))
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind - what about duplicate param names? :) The version of the inverse URI building function I'm using supports query params as `map(xs:string, xs:string*)`, meaning that one param can have multiple values. So in this case would it be possible to parse them as a `xs:string*` sequence?

Comment: Yeah, if handling multiple param with the same name, then would need to have a map available, and append values as you are putting new entries. `map:put($map, $key, (map:get($map, $key), $value) )`

Answer (score 1):

2 more answers by [Christian Grün](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1018790/christian-gr%c3%bcn):

```
let $querystring := "a=1&amp;b=2&amp;a=3"
return map:merge(
  for $query in tokenize($querystring, "&amp;")
  let $param := tokenize($query, "=")
  return map:entry(head($param), tail($param)),
  map { 'duplicates': 'combine' }
)
```

> One more solution (if you don’t wanna use the for clause):

```
let $querystring := "a=1&amp;b=2&amp;a=3"
return map:merge(
  tokenize($querystring, "&amp;")
  ! array { tokenize(., "=") }
  ! map:entry(.(1), .(2)),
  map { 'duplicates': 'combine' }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

let's see - substring to  get ? and strip any trailing #... fragment identifier
then tokenize on [&;] (actually [;&] to  get name=value pairs, which are separated by & or (less commonly) ;
then substring-before and after, or tokenize again, to get before and after the = (name value)
then uridecode the name and the value  separately

```
let $query := substring-after($uri, '?'),
     $beforefrag := substring-before($query || '#', '#')
return
  tokenize($beforefrag, '[;&amp;]')
  ! [substring-before(., '='), substring-after(., '=') ]
  ! map:entry(local:uridecode(.(1), local:uridecode(.(2))
```

might give us a sequene of map entries, and we can use map:merge on that.

If  we know our input  is plausibly encoded, we could use

```
declare function local:uridecode($input as xs:string?) as xs:string?
{
   parse-xml-fragment(replace($input, '=(..)', '&#38;x$1;'))
};
```

but a better version would just replace the two hex characters. It's really unfortunate we  don't have a version of replace() that takes a function argument to be called for each matching  subexpression, ala perl's e flag.```

and of course you can put that into

```
(...) => map:merge()
```